# How do I use a list of numbers as indexes in a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a file with multiple single-lines of letter (in this case, DNA sequences).

`list = ["AATCGATCGG","GACTCGGTTA","AGGGGTACTA"]`

I have indexes of interest that I would like to look at for each line, which I have put in a list.

`idx = [7,8,9]`

I would like to code to go through each line of list and look at each of the positions in idx within the line. How can I get a list of numbers to be read as individual index values within a loop?
Edit: I would like the output to look similar to what is below:

```
CGG
TTA
CTA
```

When I look at a specific index, using the code below, I get output for that position.

`for line in list: print(line[7])`

However, when I try to use the list of indexes in place of the specific index, using a variation of the code below:

`for line in list: print(line[idx])`

I get errors indicating that the the list items are not being read individually.

"TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not list"
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"

How do I get a list to be iterated through within a for loop?

Comment: Would really help if you can provide the expected output given the above example. E.g. do you want 7,8,9 indexed values in each line, OR 7th letter of the first line, 8th letter of the second line, and 9th value in third line?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you want the output formatting. The code below shows two alternatives. Note `list` has a specific use in Python so is best not used as a name.

```
my_list = ["AATCGATCGG","GACTCGGTTA","AGGGGTACTA"]

idx = [7,8,9]

for line in my_list:
    my_extract = [line[i] for i in idx]
    my_string = "".join(my_extract)
    print(my_extract)
    print(my_string)
```

gives:

```
['C', 'G', 'G']
CGG
['T', 'T', 'A']
TTA
['C', 'T', 'A']
CTA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a regular for loop.

```
dna_lists = ["AATCGATCGG","GACTCGGTTA","AGGGGTACTA"]
for line in dna_lists:
    print("".join([line[i] for i in idx])
```

The following list comprehension forms a new list using the indexed letters in the sequence.

```
[line[i] for i in idx]
```

The `"".join(list)` form is used for creating a string from the list members.

Answer (score -1):

To make sure the items in the list are being read individually you need to do :

```
for i in list :
```

or

```
list = [ ]
b = list[1:2]
c = list[2:3]
d = list[3:4]
e = list[4:5]
f = list[5:6]
g = list[6:7]

print(b,c,d,e,f,g)
```